# single click without mouse drag in GLFW

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I'm making a GUI system for my 3D game engine using GLFW and I need my UI objects like my buttons to only perform their functions when they are clicked once.

The program checks if the user clicked in the button's area by checking the cursor's coordinates, but the problem is that if the user clicks and drags within the button area, then the button's functions are called repeatedly. Is there a way to stop this?

```
void ui_Button::click(void (*f)())
{
    if (mouseX >= pPosX && mouseX <= pWidth && mouseY >= pPosY && mouseY <= pHeight && glfwGetMouseButton(window, GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT))
    {
        (*f)();
    }
}
```

Another option I was thinking about but don't know how to do is having the button's functions work when the mouse is clicked and released on the button or UI object.

Comment: Set a boolean `clicked` to true when clicked, false when released, and only call the button function when it's false.

Comment: @AdamS That would cause the button to be pressed when the mouse is dragged over it while holding lmb.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the code is called in a loop so it would cause the button functions to always run

Comment: @Cubic Not a button specific boolean, but a global mouse boolean. But the callback solution is the better anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this would be to install a mouse listener with `glfwSetMouseButtonCallback` that keeps a list of things interested in mouse key presses, and informs them of that (basically, like the observer pattern).